# Web API routing give same response on 2 differend calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, webapi, rest

I Made simple router using Express and Node.JS
(Github Repo with code: https://github.com/michalwitek1232/back )

I have 2 separate routes, one for 'recipes' and another for 'przepisy'.

My router script:

```js
const Recipe = require("../models/recipe.model.js");
const Przepis = require("../models/przepis.model.js");

module.exports = app => {
    const Recipe = require("../controllers/recipe.controller.js");
    const Przepis = require("../controllers/recipe.controller.js");
  
    // Create a new Recipe
    app.post("/recipe", Recipe.create);
  
    // Retrieve all Recipe
    app.get("/recipes", Recipe.findAll);
  
    // Delete a Recipe with recipeId
    app.delete("/recipe/:recipeId", Recipe.delete);
  
    // Create a new Recipe
    app.delete("/recipe", Recipe.deleteAll);

    // * przepisy ale po polsku bo angielski leży ;P

    //dodawanie przepisu
    app.post("/przepis", Przepis.create);

    //pobieranie przepisów
    app.get("/przepisy", Przepis.findAll);

    //pobieranie po id
    /*
    TODO: dodać
    app.get("/przepis/przepisId", Przepis.findOne);
    */

    //edycja po id
    /*
    TODO: dodać
    app.put("/przepis/:przepisId", Przepis.update);*/

    //Usuwanie przepisu po Id
    app.delete("/przepis/:przepisId", Przepis.delete);

    //usuwanie wszystkich
    app.delete("/przepis", Przepis.deleteAll);

  };
```

But when I am making call in Postman to `localhost:3000/przepisy`, it is returning the same response as `localhost:3000/recipes` which is weird, because there are 2 separate queries:

Recipes:

```
SELECT * FROM recipies
```

Przepisy:

```
SELECT * FROM przepisy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the same controller for two tables.

> ```
> const Recipe = require("../controllers/recipe.controller.js");
> const Przepis = require("../controllers/recipe.controller.js");
> ```

And when you called findAll it called the first defined function from the '../controllers/recipe.controller.js' controller, and it's working with the Recipe model. That's why you got the same response.

> As a solution create a separate controller for the models.